# JavaFX TableCell editable depending on row value

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecell

I have a `TableView` with multiple columns and I want some of them to be editable only if a value is verified on another column of the same row. In other words, I want the "editable" property of the `TableCell` to be row-specific instead of column-specific.

The real problem is I can't find any way to get the `TableCell` object from the column, and thus I am unable to set its editable property to false.

Could you help me do it? Is it even possible with JavaFX?

---

For example, this would be the column in where to check the "editable" property:

```
nextIsEditableCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Boolean>("nextIsEditable"));
nextIsEditableCol.setCellFactory(ChoiceBoxTableCell.<Person,Boolean>forTableColumn(true,false));
nextIsEditableCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, Boolean>>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, Boolean> t) {
        if(t.getNewValue()){
            //Here be the code that sets the next cell of this row to editable
        }
    }
});
```

And this would be the column that may or may not be editable:

```
mayBeEditedCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name"));
mayBeEditedCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
nextIsEditableCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Person, String>>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Person, Boolean> t) {
        t.getRowValue().setName(t.getNewValue);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you want it to be row specific instead of column specific?

You could use a cell change listener. Whenever a cell is changed you would get the x,y coords of the cell. You could create an array of booleans like `isColumnDependent`. If the value is true, you could then determine the number of columns, and create a method that iterates through the cells to the left and right of it disabling the editablility of them if the desired rule is not met.

Just an idea, haven't worked with JavaFX much.

If it is anything like JTable's setup, you could create a more row oriented table model.

Comment: The real problem is I can't find any way to get the TableCell object from the column, and thus I am unable to set its editable property to false.

Comment: Suggest editing your question to indicate this. The easier people can understand your question, the more likely you are to get an answer.

Comment: Also, try checking the superclass methods. See if there is one that you can use for your needs.